# Установка сервлетов

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день, пытаюсь установить Tomcat server , выдает ошибку,что нет артефактов. Не могу понять, что делать

Comment: перейдите на вкладку деплоймент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавь артефакт на вкладке Deployment(можно сразу оба добавить)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]